# How to push with Sourcetree from Branch to Master

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I have a master branch and a featureBranch.
Our companies default is to rebase the featureBranch to the master so that the featureBranch is uptodate with the master.
Then to push the featureBranch to the master

```
git push origin featureBranch:master
```

How can I achive this with Sourcetree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you push to a remote, SourceTree gives you the option to specify which local branch(es) to push, as well as which remote branch to push to.

[image]